# android not receiving broadcast

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i my app i am sending an broadcast from the `onTaskRemoved()` method of a `service`. But i am not getting the `broadcast` in the `broadcastReciever`. This is my code

```
    @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

            Log.e("TaskRemoved","TaskRemoved");
                commonSessionManager.setConnected(false);
            broadCastUpdate(GymMainActivity.APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS);
        }

        public void broadCastUpdate(String action){

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(GymMainActivity.APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS,action);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    private BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    final String action = intent.getAction();

                    if (WRONG_DATA.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                        Toast.makeText(GymMainActivity.this, "Please measure your vitals again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        isFalseDataSent = true;
                    }

                    if (ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                        Toast.makeText(GymMainActivity.this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (!isFinishing()) {
                                    ShowConnectDialog();
                                }


                            }
                        });

                    } else if (ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                        Toast.makeText(GymMainActivity.this, "disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                        connectDialog.dismiss();
                        String[] result = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_DATA);
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            Log.e("result " + i, result[i]);
                        }

                        Log.e("isDisplayed", isDisplayed + "");
                        if (!isDisplayed) {
                            if (isFalseDataSent) {
                                mBluetoothController.powerOff();
                                isFalseDataSent = false;
                            }

                            commonSessionManager.setConnected(true);
                            Intent vitalDataIntent = new Intent(GymMainActivity.this, GymVitalDisplayActivity.class);
                                    vitalDataIntent.putExtra("userDataBundle",userDataBundle());
                                    vitalDataIntent.putExtra("vitalData", result);
                                    startActivity(vitalDataIntent);
                                    finish();
                            isDisplayed = true;
                        }

                    }

                    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS)){

                        Toast.makeText(GymMainActivity.this,"APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btnScan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        if(btnConnect.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                            btnConnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        if(txtConnected.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                            txtConnected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
                final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
                intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
                intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
                intentFilter.addAction(WRONG_DATA);
                intentFilter.addAction(APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS);
                return intentFilter;
            }


                public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
                    "com.example.demo.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
            public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
                    "com.example.demo.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
            public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
                    "com.example.demo.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
            public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
                    "com.example.demo.le.EXTRA_DATA";
            public final static String WRONG_DATA =
                    "com.example.demo.le.WRONG_DATA";
            public final static String APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS="com.example.demo.le.APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS";
```

i am receiving all the broadcast except `APP_REMOVED_FROM_RECENTS.`

Comment: Can you post a formatted code?

Comment: from API: `This is called if the service is currently running and the user has removed a task that comes from the service's application. If you have set ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply be stopped.`  are you sure that your app fullfills the expectations?

Comment: no i have not set ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK

Comment: and does your user remove a task anywhere? for example stop a certain activity or something like this?

Comment: this is called only when the user removes the app from the recents screen

Comment: all i want to do is show a certain button and hide another button for which i sent a broadcast from the onTaskRemoved() method and wrote the show/hide code in the broadcast receiver method. but since i am not receiving the broadcast i am managing it through sharedPreferences.  Sorry i am not able to correctly edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're not setting the action on the intent but as an extra. Change your code to that and see if it works:

```
public void broadCastUpdate(String action){
    Intent intent=new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: no sorry its not working, is it possible to generate a broadcast from onTaskRemoved() ?